# How to raise an action through an interactivity trigger at an unittest?

Tags: c#, wpf, vs-unit-testing-framework

i got some little problems. I want to write some unittest fora c#/wpf/interactivty project with visual studio 2010. and dont forget im a beginner, so sorry for that  ;)

the unittest should simulate a (virtual) Key Down Event on a textbox and the result should raise an action.(Action result: Console output - just to check as first step)

i still fixed 2 problems -> the dispatcher problem & the presentationSource bug.

The unittest still simulates the keyevent and the keyevent reached the textbox but the question is, why the action not raised through the keydown event on the textbox?

It's a threading problem? what's my missunderstand?

here is the code

The Unittest
*at the end of the unittest u could check the textbox - the keyboard works*

```
[TestMethod]
public void simpleTest()
{
    var mockWindow = new MockWindow();

    //simple test to check if the virtualKeyboard works
    string CheckText = "Checktext";

    mockWindow.SendToUIThread(mockWindow.textbox, CheckText);

    mockWindow.SendToUIThread(mockWindow.textbox, "k");

    //needed to start the dispatcher
    DispatcherUtil.DoEvents();
}
```

the Dispatcher fix

```
public static class DispatcherUtil
    {
        [SecurityPermissionAttribute(SecurityAction.Demand, Flags = SecurityPermissionFlag.UnmanagedCode)]
        public static void DoEvents()
        {
            DispatcherFrame frame = new DispatcherFrame();
            Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Background, new DispatcherOperationCallback(ExitFrame), frame);
            Dispatcher.PushFrame(frame);
        }

        private static object ExitFrame(object frame)
        {
            ((DispatcherFrame)frame).Continue = false;
            return null;
        }
    }
```

My Testaction

```
 class TestAction : TriggerAction<UIElement>
    {
        protected override void Invoke(object parameter)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("testAction invoke");
        }
    }
```

The MockWindow

```
public class MockWindow : Window
{
    public TextBox textbox { get; private set; }

    public MockWindow()
    {    
        //add a grid&textbox
        Grid grid = new Grid();
        textbox = new TextBox();

        this.Content = grid;
        grid.Children.Add(textbox);

        //create the testaction/triggerEvent & add them
        TestAction testAction = new TestAction();
        System.Windows.Interactivity.EventTrigger TestTrigger = new System.Windows.Interactivity.EventTrigger();
        TestTrigger.EventName = "KeyDown";
        TestTrigger.Actions.Add(testAction);
        TestTrigger.Attach(this.textbox);
    }

    //enter a keyboard press on an UIElement
    public void SendToUIThread(UIElement element, string text)
    {
        element.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
        {
            SendKeys.Send(element, text);
        }), DispatcherPriority.Input);
    }
}
```

the MockKeyboard added from [codeplex sendkeys](http://wpfsendkeys.codeplex.com/) + a presentationCore fix for unittest(added at class SendKeys)

```
public class FixPresentationSource : PresentationSource
{
    protected override CompositionTarget GetCompositionTargetCore()
    {
        return null;
    }

    public override Visual RootVisual { get; set; }

    public override bool IsDisposed { get { return false; } }
}
```

Comment: i found the problem - the InteractivityFramework is the problem. Ok no real problem just an insuperable wall for unittesting. The result is: the InteractivityFramework check the IsLoaded property(if true) and its immo not possible to set it true without visualbuild the textbox(window).  - the rest works well(simulate keyinput + raise some keydown events on the textbox all without visualbuild.)